# Is it possible to use VC++ 2013 toolchain with VC++ Express 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I can only install VC++ 2005 on my system but also want C++11 features on it, so I must have a newer toolchain.

So, Is it possible to use VC++2013 toolchain with Visual C++ Express 2005 without installing the whole VS2013/VC++2013 IDE (e.g. by copying just binaries)?

Comment: You cant install the IDE but somehow you can (manually) install the 2013 toolchain? Odd...

Comment: I'm using Wine, my Windows 8.1 install is broken and can't boot to it. I really don't have the time to refresh my Windows and install all apps again. I decided to install Lubuntu and Wine, then run a compatible version of VC++ Express on it (which is why I'm using 2005). Also, I want C++11 features that VC++ Express 2005 doesn't have. What I'm asking is very clear: Is it possible to add 2013 toolchain to VC++ Express 2005 IDE?

Comment: @Borgleader I have VS2013 on the broken Windows 8.1, so I thought this way I can benefit from its newer toolchain :)

Comment: So you don't have time to reinstall Windows, but you have time to deal with unsupported configurations? My recommendation is that now you have Lubuntu installed, install VirtualBox, install a Windows virtual machine, and install the new version of VS on it.

Comment: I'm currently sticking with Lubuntu and want VS on it. I just asked if it is possible! A man who knows, just answers the question not making excuses, and a man who can't just says "I don't know". It' s StackOverflow, and it's a "Q/A website". I wonder why people really like making excuses compared to answering a question.

Comment: And yes, I don't have time to reinstall Windows but have time to deal with unsupported configurations, particularly because of the amount of data I have (1.8TB on a 2TB HDD) on my laptop and huge amount of apps I have to install and the time it takes me to configure the environment again. I don't really like this situation, I like to use Windows 10 with VS2015 but Win10 has the death sleep problem on my laptop and I **have to** use the sleep capability. But this way, I think it consumes much less time of me. (It's just my own opinion. I know it's better to have it on a clean Windows Install.)